# Installing a RabbitMQ cluster using puppet

Tags: installation, puppet, cluster, rabbitmq

Is there an existing puppet module that installs a RabbitMQ in cluster mode? A module I can base on my solution is good as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [puppet labs module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/rabbitmq) has had the [cluster support code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq/pull/26) merged into master in [git](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq) 3 months ago but it hasn't been officially released yet.